# How to add space between strings in an array and concatenate it in a format for csv?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm currently using the following approach:

```
var authorsNameList = authors.map(x => x.FirstName + ' ' + x.LastName);
```

However, this returns a result like this:

```
Bob Smith,Bill Jones,Nancy Smith
```

But I need the result to look like this:

```
Bob Smith, Bill Jones, Nancy Smith
```

Comment: So use join() with whatever you want? Or reduce....

Comment: Use `.join(', ')` and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concat a space at the beginning and trim() your string to remove spaces.

Something like:

```
var authorsNameList = authors.map(x => ' '+x.FirstName + ' ' + x.LastName).join().trim();
```

Comment: even better would be to `join` with `, ` rather than the default `,`